# How to write exactly bash scripts into Makefiles?

Tags: bash, make

I love to type bash scripts, but if I prepare multiple tools, project's root directory is filled with so many shell scripts. That's why I prefer using Makefile.

Makefile is good. However I want to build my makefiles just as regular bash scripts.

Eg:

Think that I wrote a bash script very quickly with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
cd ~
do-some-work.sh my-parameter
```

I can run this script with `$ ./my-important-task.sh`.

If I wanted to move that script into makefile, I should do the following:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash 

my-important-task: 
    echo "hello" ;\
    cd ~ ;\
    do-some-work.sh my-parameter
```

but I want the following:

```
my-important-task: 
    [[copy and paste the my-important-task.sh file]]
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you really want to “write exactly bash scripts into Makefiles” then you'll need to do it a bit indirectly. If you just paste the script after the target line, then you'll run into two problems that just cannot be bypassed: the command lines need to be indented with a tab, and dollar signs need to be escaped.

If you use GNU make (as opposed to BSD make, Solaris make, etc.), then you can define your script as a variable using the [multi-line definition syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html#Multi_002dLine), and then use the [`value` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Value-Function.html#Value-Function) to use the raw value of the variable, bypassing expansion.

In addition, [as explained by skwllsp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270781), you need to tell make to execute the command list for each target as a single shell script rather than line by line, which you can do in GNU make by [defining a `.ONESHELL` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html).

```
define my_important_task =
# script goes here
endef

my-important-task: ; $(value my_important_task)

.ONESHELL:
```

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this file: https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/a380bb92cbd03c34aba5

Comment: @ceremcem You need `.ONESHELL` as well.

Comment: When using .ONESHELL, probably want to start the recipe with 'set -e'. Without ONESHELL the recipe will abort on first error; but with ONESHELL (and SHELL = /bin/bash) the recipe will not abort on error. 'set -e' goes back to abort on error

Comment: This is very useful to be able to have a bash code snippet inside the makefile. How to I access the variables from makefile within the script. Or is there a way to pass a variable to 'my_important_task'

Comment: You can export a make variable to the environment. Look up `export` in the GNU make manual.

Answer (score 14):

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html

> If the .ONESHELL special target appears anywhere in the makefile then
>   all recipe lines for each target will be provided to a single
>   invocation of the shell.

You will still need to put a tab character at the beginning of each line, and to double all dollar signs (i.e. replace `$` by `$$` everywhere in the script).

Comment: it's almost what I'm looking for. would you mind helping me debug the following test code which doesn't work as is: https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/9b6e8e90928ff4afc569

Comment: @ceremcem You need to escape the dollar signs.

Comment: It still produces an error: [```make: /bin/bash : Command not found
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 127```](https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/9b6e8e90928ff4afc569#gistcomment-1728223)

Comment: @ceremcem, what make version do you use? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153034/oneshell-not-working-properly-in-makefile

Comment: @Gilles I use GNU Make 4.1

Comment: This is way better than $(value VAR)

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is that your top-level project directory is cluttered with dozens of scripts, then the obvious solution is to create a subdirectory (e.g. called `scripts`) to put them in.

Run them as `./scripts/scriptname` and/or add the scripts directory to your PATH.

If you still want a Makefile to run them with, just create Makefile entries that run `./scripts/scriptname` for those targets. e.g.

```
my-important-task: 
    ./scripts/my-important-task.sh my-parameter
```

NOTE: If the scripts in ./scripts call other scripts in the same directory, they'll need to either specify the full path to the script, or have the scripts directory in the PATH.

Comment: Maybe that would be an appropriate solution. But writing down in a single file would make things speed up in most cases. We were talking about [a proposal yesterday](https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/26fbf6b44099c788c887) though...

Comment: somehow i doubt very much that having `make` parse a Makefile, search for a target, and then fork a shell to run some shell commands could possibly be faster than just running a shell script.  not that the startup speed of make plus a bunch of shell commands or a shell script is at all significant on any modern-ish machine (say, less than 20 years old) unless run thousands of times in a loop.

Answer (score -1):

BTW ... you can not just use Bash.

In fact you can write make target recipes in any scripting language you want.

Example snippet using Python:

```
...
SHELL != sh -c "command -v python"
.SHELLFLAGS := -c
.ONESHELL:

# et voilà : the recipe can now be written in pure python :-)
all: foo    
    # use some make variables
    print "# target name is '$@', depends on '$^'"

    import os
    print os.listdir ("..")

foo:
    # use some make variables
    print "# target name is '$@', depends on '$^'"

    import sys
    print 'python version is %s.%s.%s' % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1], sys.version_info[2])
...
```

see an example in various languages : https://github.com/lgersman/make-recipes-in-different-scripting-languages-demo